# Pull payment for automatic payment transfer.

Tags: ether, payments

How can I program my wallet such that all Ether sent to it is immediately and automatically transferred to my other wallet within a minute.

Answer (score 2):

### Example

You are looking to effectively **'forward'** your balance. A way to go about doing this is using a contract similar to the one  highlighted [Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/32284/31518).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

/**
 * Contract that will forward any incoming Ether to its creator
 */
contract Forwarder {
  // Address to which any funds sent to this contract will be forwarded
  address public destinationAddress;

  /**
   * Create the contract, and set the destination address to that of the creator
   */
  function Forwarder() public {
    destinationAddress = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * Default function; Gets called when Ether is deposited, and forwards it to the destination address
   */
  function() payable public {
        destinationAddress.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  /**
   * It is possible that funds were sent to this address before the contract was deployed.
   * We can flush those funds to the destination address.
   */
  function flush() public {
    destinationAddress.transfer(this.balance);
  }

}
```

---

### Source

Fully audited repo with code used to test, please do be aware of the constraint that is creating each account with said paradigm:

https://github.com/Meshugah/ERC20-CommonGasWallet